# How to replace such text

Tags: linux, sed

I have a lot of file and I have to replace such text:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

I tried with grep like:

```
cat filename | sed '<script type=\"text\/javascript\"\nsrc=\"http:\/\/pagead2\.googlesyndication\.com\/pagead\/show_ads\.js\">\n<\/script>'
```

But this won't work, any ideas?

Comment: You may find [this](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/) and [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/ch06_01.htm#SEDAWK-CH-6-SECT-1) of interest.

Comment: single quote seems need to be in double quote, OR try `\r\n`

Comment: It appears a simple sed script will not work if there's a newline in what you are trying to match, however there are some complicated workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

this uses sed across several lines, replace BLAH with whatever you want to search for and it will be replaced with nothing

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/BLAH//g;p}' {} \;
```